# Any interactive XAML editor for WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Is there an interactive XAML editor that can be used with WPF out there, or some way to use VisualStateManager in XamlPadX 4.0?

I've tried XamlPadX 4.0 which was great until I tried to do something using the VisualStateManager which it choked on. Cursory research indicates that VisualStateManager support arrived in WPF in Dotnet 4 whereas XamlPadX 4 is built using Dotnet 2.5. Attempting to redirect XamlPadX to use Dotnet 4 has not been successful.

Blend, as far as I an tell, doesn't appear to have an interactive mode, just a standard VS style code/run iteration cycle.

I've had a quick look at Kaxaml. It seems to work but is pretty limited, e.g. no visual tree explorer.

UPDATE Blend features suggested by colinsmith

I have VS2012 Update 2 installed and I've tried using Blend but with no success. Entering the following code for example and selecting the Button from the "Objects and Timeline" panel results in the "Objects and Timeline" panel displaying "(No Storyboard open)" and there being nothing at all in the States panel. Clicking Help in Blend takes me to an MSDN page stating "We are sorry. The page you requested cannot be found." and searching the web for guidance on using Blend for VS2012 with WPF throws up nothing, which doesn't surprise me greatly since support for WPF was only added to Blend for VS2012 in VS2012 Update 2 which was only released a couple of days ago.

```xml
<Window x:Class="BlendScratchProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="91" Width="192">

    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Button Content="Button">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Border x:Name="_rootElement">
                        <Border.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush x:Name="_borderBrush" Color="Black"/>
                        </Border.Background>

                        <Grid Margin="4">
                            <Grid.Background>
                                <SolidColorBrush x:Name="_backgroundBrush" Color="Green"/>
                            </Grid.Background>

                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                Margin="5"/>
                        </Grid>

                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">

                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>

                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="_borderBrush"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Color" To="Red" Duration="0:0:0"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>

                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Comment: You probably know this already....but there's always Expression Blend....you can check out the Preview http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30702 ... that one works with WPF/.NET 4....don't know if it requires VS2012 to be present on your system...something to check out. Or perhaps you're looking for a "free" option?

Comment: I couldn't find any interactive mode in Blend, is there one?

Comment: You want the States panel in order to design the states for your VSM. http://www.oshyn.com/_blog/General/post/Using_Visual_State_Manager_and_Toggle_Button/ ... make sure you are using that Blend Preview version mentioned .... or you should be ok with EXpression Blend 4. Visual Studio 2012 Update 2, now builds WPF support into the Visual Studio Blend.

Comment: I think I'm not making myself clear. By interactive I mean what I type gets displayed as a live UI as it does in XamlPadX, rather than dragging stuff about on a designer surface which you can then run to see what it actually looks like.

Answer (score 1):

In Blend make sure "Transition Preview" is enabled in the States panel, then you can just switch between the states (by clicking on them) in your state group to see the animation.

See option 5 on this link:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/apps/jj129458.aspx.

(Note: the icon looks different depending on the edition of Blend!).

Apart from that you have the regular "split" mode so you can see the XAML text editor and type raw XAML in and see it rendered as you type (i.e. as per Kaxaml, etc).

Sorry, if that's not what you want, or I'm being dense understanding you...

Picture below, highlighting the bits to select.

[image]

Caveat:

Just make sure that you have an edition of Blend that supports WPF...WPF support was left out of the Blend that came with Visual Studio 2012 RTM...to get it back you had to use download and use "BLEND + SKETCHFLOW PREVIEW FOR VISUAL STUDIO 2012"....but now there's a proper RTM version in Visual Studio Update 2.

If you're not using Visual Studio 2012, then just use the separate Expression Blend 4 product (or get it as part of Expression Studio).